# Fatal Error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: centos7, python-3.11

Trying to run Python 3.11 on CentOS 7 and keep getting this error block anytime I invoke python3.11.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3.11'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/usr/local/lib/python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.11'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.11'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f11582b4740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

I have tried setting paths and deconflicting the references to other python versions on the device.

Answer (score 0):

just unset PATH. It helped me. I had the same issue when build cpython from sources and try to use it in C code. After unsetting the PATH all problems gone out